# Map HashCode and Equals

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve the value of the another element in the HashMap overriding equals and hashcode method. Why the rollId is returned null when I am having the same hashcode for student1 and student3 and also these 2 objects are equal? Ideally it should return me 3. Below is the code snippet:

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Student, Integer> studentMap = new HashMap<Student, Integer>();
    Student student1 = new Student();
    student1.setRollId(1);
    Student student2 = new Student();
    student2.setRollId(2);
    studentMap.put(student1, 1);
    studentMap.put(student2, 2);
    for (Entry<Student, Integer> entry : studentMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(1)) {
            student1.setRollId(3);
        }
    }
    Student student3 = new Student();
    student3.setRollId(3);
    System.out.println("Student1 HashCode " + student1.hashCode()
            + " Student3 HashCode " + student3.hashCode());
    System.out.println("Object Equal === > " + student1.equals(student3));
    Integer rollId = studentMap.get(student3);
    System.out.println("RollId is " + rollId);

}
```

**Student Class**

```
private Integer rollId;

public Integer getRollId() {
    return rollId;
}

public void setRollId(Integer rollId) {
    this.rollId = rollId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return rollId;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Student student = (Student)obj;
    if(this.rollId.equals(student.getRollId()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You should post the entire code rather than snippets so that helpers can test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HashMap` eventually stores the key-value pairs in a table, and it uses the hashcode of the given key to compute the index within the table for its mapped value.

When you modify the `rollId` attribute, you would also modify the hash code of the key, which in turn would cause a lookup in the internal table for a different index than the one the map *originally* used to store the value.

For example, the table may have been initially allocated with a certain capacity of 16, and the two pair entries were stored at indices 1 and 2 (given the `rollId` set in the `Student` object). After changing the hash key from 1 to 3, the map would search 
index 3 which does not store any value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the hash key after it's put in the map and expect the map to continue to work correctly.  When you want to change a key, you must remove the item, change the key, and reinsert.

From the Java documentation:

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

Comment: Thanks @Gene. Got it... It is a mutable object. Upvote for the answer.

Comment: This answer, while a true statement, does not explain the problem in his code .. studentMap has no entries added .. so the student1 rollId is never changed.  See answer below

Comment: @ErstwhileIII  Maybe he changed his code after you looked at it?  But this `studentMap.put(student1, 1); studentMap.put(student2, 2);` was there when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you did not add any values to the `studentMap`.  Also, I don't understand why you are using Integer for `RollId` and calculating an int from that for your hashCode. If you really do need Integer for the greater range, there is a chance that the 32-bit `hashcode` (as you calculated) my produce a duplicate for different `rollIds`.  Consider changing to int/

Try this code:

**StudentDriver Class**

```
package com.example.student;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class StudentDriver {
    private static Student student1, student2, student3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Student, Integer> studentMap = new HashMap<Student, Integer>();

        student1 = new Student();
        student2 = new Student();

        student1.setRollId(1);
        student2.setRollId(2);

        studentMap.put(student1, student1.getRollId());
        studentMap.put(student2, student2.getRollId());

        for (Entry<Student, Integer> entry : studentMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Entry information: " + entry.getValue());
            if (entry.getValue().equals(1)) {

                student1.setRollId(3);
            }
        }

        student3 = new Student();
        student3.setRollId(3);

        System.out.println("Student1 Hashcode = " + student1.hashCode()
                          +", Student3 Hashcode = " + student3.hashCode()) ;  
        System.out.println("Object equal ==> " + student1.equals(student3));
        Integer rollId = student3.getRollId();
        System.out.println("RollId is " + rollId);
    }
}
```

**Student class**

```
package com.example.student;

public class Student {
    // Object fields
    private Integer rollId;

    public Integer getRollId() {
        return rollId;
    }
    public Student setRollId(Integer rollId) {
        this.rollId = rollId;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return rollId.intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other instanceof Student && ((Student)other).getRollId() == rollId;
    }
}
```